# Android HelloViews Spinner Tutorial R.id and R.array can not be resolved

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest

I am having trouble with the Android HelloViews Spinner Tutorial. The error in HelloSpinner.java states that "R.id cannot be resolved" and "R.array cannot be resolved". The error in AndroidManifest.xml states that there is "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name')" and "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name')".

Here is my complete code:

HelloSpinner.java

```
package net.brianwolf.hellospinner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class HelloSpinner extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        android.widget.Spinner spinner = (android.widget.Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
    }
    public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {
          Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The planet is " +
              parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
          // Do nothing.
        }
    }
}
```

res/layout/main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="@string/planet_prompt"
    />
    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/planet_prompt"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

res/layoutvalues/strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="planet_prompt">Choose a planet</string>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
        <item>Jupiter</item>
        <item>Saturn</item>
        <item>Uranus</item>
        <item>Neptune</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="net.brianwolf.hellospinner"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".HelloSpinner"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `strings.xml` (or `values.xml`, whatever it's called):

`<string name="app_name">The Name Of Your App Goes Here</string>`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using Eclipse, have you tried cleaning the project? Project > Clean...

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I'm new to Android programming (and Java), and this saved me from knocking my head against the wall trying to figure out why R.array was not working as advertised.  Thanks. +1

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
<string name="app_name">The Name Of Your App Goes Here</string>
```

wont help here, Still got the problem "R" cannot be resolved to a variable from " setContentView(R.layout.main);" in the hellospinner.java

I clicked on the error symbol and it told me to link all "R" to net.brianwolf.hellospinner.R; and now it works

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem on this tutorial.  What MatrixFrog suggested didn't work for me initially either, but it led me down the right path and after further research I found the problem (in the context of the tutorial) was in the AndroidManifest.xml file.  Here's what it should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.hellospinner"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/planet_prompt">
        <activity android:name=".HelloSpinnerActivity"
                  android:label="@string/planet_prompt">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Notice the only changes are to the two places where it initially referenced `app_name`, they now reference `planet_prompt` to match the tutorials code.  This seems like a minor detail the tutorial missed and probably an obvious fix for seasoned android dev's, but really frustrating for a beginner... it is a tutorial after all.

Answer (score 1):

http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/03/corrections-for-android-tutorial-hello.html